# How to hide the variable price from single product only in woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide the variable price from the product page only, not from all thr other pages like the shop page. And i dont want the price for each variation to be hidden. Only the range variable price. I have searched all the web but all the solution hide the price from the shop also or hide the price for each variation also.

Answer (score 1):

In your **content-single-product.php** woocommerce template, you can hide the range variable price only in product page by removing the single price function from the single product summary action :

```
global $product;
if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price' );
}
```